# return class properties as JSON

Tags: php

I'm trying to encode some properties in a class in php to JSON but all my method is returning is {}

Here's my code, where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

```
    <?php

    class Person  
    {  
        private $_photo;  
        private $_name;  
        private $_email;  


        public function __construct($photo, $name, $email)  
        {  
    $this->_photo = $photo;  
            $this->_name = $name;  
            $this->_email = $email;  

        }  



       public function getJsonData() {
          $json = new stdClass;
          foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $name => $value) {
             $this->$name = $value;
          }
          return json_encode($json);
       }


    }  


    $person1 = new Person("mypicture.jpg", "john doe", "doeman@gmail.com");  

    print_r( $person1->getJsonData() );
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using $json not $this inside your foreach loop? You don't seem to be assigning any values to $json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's is because you are not using the $json variable but instead you are using $this->$name. Which $this are you refering too? You aren't using the $json variable from what I am seeing.

`class Person  
{  
    private $_photo;  
    private $_name;  
    private $_email;  


    public function __construct($photo, $name, $email)  
    {  
$this->_photo = $photo;  
        $this->_name = $name;  
        $this->_email = $email;  

    }  



   public function getJsonData() {
      //I'd make this an array
      //$json = new stdClass;
      $json = array();

      foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $name => $value) {
         //Here is my change
         //$this->$name = $value;
         $json[$name] = $value
      }
      return json_encode($json);
   }


}  


$person1 = new Person("mypicture.jpg", "john doe", "doeman@gmail.com");  

print_r( $person1->getJsonData() );`

Hope it solves you problem. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [JsonSerializable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface in your class, starting with PHP 5.4.